# How do I change specific channels with the curves tool in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, channel

When I click the "Channel" dropdown in the Curves tool in GIMP, all of the channels are grayed out and I can only select "Value". What would cause them to be grayed out? What do I need to do to change the color curves of particular color channels?

[image: Curves]

Answer (score 3):

The channels become grayed out whenever the image is not using the usual RGB mode (in other the words image is grayscale or color-indexed). To change the color mode, click "Image" -> "Mode" -> "RGB". Then you will be able to use the Curves tool to its full extent.

[image: Image Mode RGB]